# Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -1073740791 which indicates an error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am getting this error while trying to export some 3d views from the Revit model to the IFC. This error happens only with big models.

Here is my log:

```
[02/11/2021 17:37:33] Log: Total amount of 3d Views in the Autodesk.Revit.DB.FilePath : 415
[02/11/2021 17:37:33] Log: 3dViews to export: 11
[02/11/2021 17:49:13] Log IFC ARK-modell exported:True
[02/11/2021 17:49:15] Log 3D IFC-eksport exported:True
[02/11/2021 17:51:02] Log Klimaskille IFC exported:True
[02/11/2021 17:51:09] Log Røde soner IFC exported:False
[02/11/2021 17:51:26] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[02/11/2021 17:51:26] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -1073740791 which indicates an error.
[02/11/2021 17:51:26] End script phase.
[02/11/2021 17:51:26] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[02/11/2021 17:51:26] Job finished with result FailedExecution

  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2021-02-11T17:28:52.9539748Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2021-02-11T17:28:53.1907405Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2021-02-11T17:30:04.9570909Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2021-02-11T17:51:26.3121192Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1799706128   },
```

I've used the same appbundle, activity and workitem which is described in this question:

[Design Automation for Revit output zipped file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068894/design-automation-for-revit-output-zipped-file-is-empty)

**WorkitemId** : 374b77b415f7403d923bab9fb3ddc412

Comment: thanks for providing the workitem id, we will look into it and get back

Comment: From what I can tell from the log, a 1.799 GB input zip file was downloaded and this WorkItem tried to work with a big revit file. After running around 23 mins, it failed. But unfortunely, I can't tell what exactly went wrong by reading the log, no more information than the report you already have.
Did you ever try this big file locally with your addin?

Comment: The input file contains linked models. After unzipping, the app works with a model size of 750 MB.
Several times I did it locally, and that works.

Comment: I've tried again, and it works in DA4R.
WorkitemId:4e2b466d00534587a70e3fb1d48e3df8