# Errors Design Automation For Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

**I am getting 2 kinds of different errors while trying to export some 3d views from the Revit model to the IFC. Here is my log:**

```
[02/15/2021 19:22:52] Log IFC-eksport RØR exported:False
[02/15/2021 19:22:57] Log IFC-eksport VENT exported:True 
[02/15/2021 19:23:19] Log IFC Beredere exported:False 
[02/15/2021 19:24:53] Log IFC-eksport Status 200511 exported:False 
[02/15/2021 19:25:25] Log IFC-eksport Status 200512 exported:False 
[02/15/2021 19:25:25] Log: Error in exporting WO_*AV_Link IFC DWG view from Autodesk.Revit.DB.FilePath [02/15/2021 19:25:25] Contains invalid characters 
[02/15/2021 19:25:25] Parameter name: name, RevitAPI 
[02/15/2021 19:25:42] Log IFC-eksport Status 200514 exported:False 
[02/15/2021 19:25:50]  Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.    at IFCTransaction.{dtor}(IFCTransaction* )    at DiscardedObjectsHospice.addOne<class IFCTransaction>(DiscardedObjectsHospice* , IFCTransaction* pMostlyDead)    at Autodesk.Revit.Proxy.DB.IFC.IFCTransactionProxy.ReleaseUnmanagedResources(Boolean disposing)    at Autodesk.Revit.Proxy.DB.IFC.IFCTransactionProxy.Dispose(Boolean A_0) 
[02/15/2021 19:25:50] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump. 
[02/15/2021 19:25:50] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -1073741819 which indicates an error. 
[02/15/2021 19:25:50] End script phase. 
[02/15/2021 19:25:50] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job. [02/15/2021 19:25:50] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

**WorkitemId is : d4536db4819d466ebfc26d81f3c99499**

*Here is log for another model:*

```
[02/15/2021 19:12:08] Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException: Opening was canceled.
[02/15/2021 19:12:08]    at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(ModelPath modelPath, OpenOptions openOptions)
[02/15/2021 19:12:08]    at IFCExportAddin.Commands.RevitExportToIFC(DesignAutomationData data)
[02/15/2021 19:12:08]    at IFCExportAddin.Commands.HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent(Object sender, DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs e)
[02/15/2021 19:12:08]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.RaiseDesignAutomationReadyEvent(DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs e)
[02/15/2021 19:12:08]    at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
[02/15/2021 19:12:13] 湥整楲杮映湩獩偨慬批捡⁫⸮搠獥牴祯洠偟慬批捡卫慴整਍਍潣瑮湩極杮映湩獩偨慬批捡⁫⸮搠獥牴祯挠污卬牴慥⡭ഩഊ攊楸整⁤楦楮桳汐祡慢正਍਍RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[02/15/2021 19:12:13] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[02/15/2021 19:12:13] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[02/15/2021 19:12:14] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[02/15/2021 19:12:14] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[02/15/2021 19:12:14] End script phase.
[02/15/2021 19:12:14] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[02/15/2021 19:12:14] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[02/15/2021 19:12:14] Job Status:
```

**WorkitemId is : cff96fe3d2fb4379bfd571bec048b177**

I've used the same appbundle, activity, and workitem which is described in this question: [Design Automation for Revit output zipped file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068894/design-automation-for-revit-output-zipped-file-is-empty)

Everything works perfectly when I debug the plugin locally.

Comment: Thanks for providing WorkItem Ids. We will check the logs and get back.

Comment: I checked the log, I cannot tell the root cause for these two failures. Since the failures happened on specific files, I think we may want the files to reproduce and try to debug from there on our side. Is it possible that you can share the files with us? If so, I will ask help from our support team to contact you to get the files. Thanks!

Comment: Yes,I'd like to share my models with you.Thank you.